# right alignment of element in li in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align `li` values right most of the screen. but it does not appear.

Codepan:  [http://codepen.io/](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/IKkCc)

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">   

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
```

`text-align:right;` or `align="right"` does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `text-align: right` to the anchor tags inside the list.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/thgaskell/pen/gAiJw)

#### CSS

```
.navbar-right li a {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using the Bootstrap pull-right class inside of your ordered list tags like so:

```
<ul class="pull-right">The text you want aligned to the right</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: right;` to the `ul` instead of the `li`